# Directive order in angularjs form validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a custom directive which validates the field and on the same field I have applied ng-pattern for checking whether the input is number or not. The problem I am facing is that the custom directive always runs before ng-pattern.

Desired Behavior-
ng-pattern->customValidator

Right now its-
customValidator->ng-pattern

I have not specified any prioriry on customValidator and also don't want to.
Is there any way that I can force this custom-validator to run after ng-pattern.

```
<input type=text ng-pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]*$/" customValidator>

.directive('customValidator', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validate);

                scope.$watch(ngModel.$viewValue, function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);
                });

                function validate(value) {
                    // validation code
                    if (validation) {
                       ngModel.$setValidity('custom', true);
                       return value;
                    }
                    else {
                       ngModel.$setValidity('custom', false);
                       return false;
                    }                  
                }
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: One way for sure is you can place pattern code test inside validate() to execute first.

Comment: I dont want to mixup the things and want to keep customvalidator reusable, so can't go for this